Issue while getting location of device in google maps flutter
I'm having an issue while getting the location of the user, having API call to get the stations and lastly placing markers on the map.
I'm using Getx as controller, so my variables are:
  LatLng _initialPosition = const LatLng(40.42, 49.82);
  var activeGps = true.obs;
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  List<NearbyStation>? _stations;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = Set();

  BitmapDescriptor _availableIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
  BitmapDescriptor _unavailabeIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;

and using getter to get them:
  LatLng get gpsPosition => _actualLocation;
  LatLng get initialPos => _initialPosition;
  List<NearbyStation>? get stations => _stations;

  Set<Marker> get markers => _markers;
  GoogleMapController get mapController => _mapController;

I have getUserLocation function which uses geolocator package and gets the accurate location:
void getUserLocation() async {
    if (!(await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled())) {
      activeGps.value = false;
    } else {
      activeGps.value = true;
      LocationPermission permission;
      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
        }
      }
      if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        return Future.error(
            'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
      }

      const LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 100,
      );
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          locationSettings: locationSettings);
      _initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      await _getStations(position.latitude, position.longitude); // used to get stations

      _mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(_initialPosition));
      _buildMarkers(); // used to build markers
    }
  }

Of course, I also have the onInit function to initialize:
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    addCustomIcon();
    getUserLocation();
  }

and _buildMarkers() function is used to add the markers to the set.
Set<Marker> _buildMarkers() {
    for (var station in _stations!) {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(station.id.toString()),
          position:
              LatLng(double.parse(station.lat), double.parse(station.long)),
          icon: station.availableConnectors > 0
              ? _availableIcon
              : _unavailabeIcon,
          onTap: () async {
            Get.toNamed('/connectors', arguments: {
              'id': station.id,
              'location': LatLng(
                double.parse(station.lat),
                double.parse(station.long),
              ),
            });
            //}
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    return markers;
  }

and lastly, _getStations() function is used to get the stations, call itself works fine, but issue happens when I try to get the locations inside getUserLocation.
  Future<List<NearbyStation>?> _getStations(
      double latitude, double longitude) async {
    final String? accessToken = box.read('access_token');
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          '${ApiConstants.baseUrl}${ApiConstants.getNearbyStationEndpoint}?long=$longitude&lat=$latitude&rad=-1');
      var response =
          await http.get(url, headers: ApiConstants.headers(accessToken));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        List<NearbyStation> station = jsonResponse
            .map((regionJson) => NearbyStation.fromJson(regionJson))
            .toList();
        _stations = station;
        return station;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  }


Solution was rather simple to this question. I had to add .obs to the markers to it would listen to changes and update accordingly:
 final Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>{}.obs;

and
Set<Marker> get markers => _markers.obs;

